# What is the meaning of this 'error: ‘send’ is not a type' in declaring mocks

Tags: mocking, tdd, googlemock

I am trying to mock `zmq.hpp`.

```
namespace zmq {
class ZmqMockSocket : public socket_t {
    MOCK_METHOD((size_t), send, (), (override));
};
```

I get the following error:

```
zmq_mock.h:16:25: error: ‘send’ is not a type
MOCK_METHOD((size_t), send, (), (override);
                      ^~~~
```

The `send` is defined class `socket_t` as :

```
virtual size_t send (void) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the MOCK_METHOD as indicated in a NEW gmock cookbook. I had the same problem, and finally found out that it's because of my OLD gtest/gmock version.

I saw this [issue](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/948), where MOCK_METHOD is supported with old gtest/gmock version. It's second argument is a type. This is the reason why your compiler sees function 'send' as a type.
Then there was this [change](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/1840) in 2018, where MOCK_METHOD(ReturnType, MethodName, (Args...)) was introduced.
You can also check in the release [v1.10.0](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.10.0).

**Solution**: Use the old style MOCK_METHODn macros or use the MOCK_METHOD with the correct order of argument.